# Method using Big Integers returns nothing

Tags: java, primes, biginteger

I created a Fermat primality test using Java's Big Integers. However, although no error shows up and everything looks fine, it won't return neither true nor false for any input (except for BigInteger.valueOf(3)).

```
public static boolean isPrime (BigInteger n){
    BigInteger counter=BigInteger.ZERO;
    boolean isPrime=false;
    if(n.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(2)))isPrime=true;
    if(n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2))>0 && n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(40))<0) {
        for (BigInteger a=BigInteger.valueOf(2);a.compareTo(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))<0;a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE),n).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) counter.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }

        if (counter.equals(n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(3)))) isPrime = true;
    }
        else {

        for (BigInteger a=BigInteger.valueOf(2);a.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(40))<=0;a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE),n).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) counter.add(BigInteger.ONE);

        }
        if (counter.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(39))) isPrime = true;
    }
    return isPrime;
}

        }
```

Is this problem occurring due to Big Integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `a.add(BigInteger.ONE)` should be `a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE)`. Otherwise your `a` always has the same value, and your loop is infinite.

See [BigInteger#add(value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)):

> Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this + val)

Comment: ...and also `counter.add(BigInteger.ONE)` to `counter = counter.add(BigInteger.ONE)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not occurring due to `BigInteger`. The function never returns because you have created infinite loops in your `for` loops:

```
for (BigInteger a=BigInteger.valueOf(2);a.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(40))<=0;a.add(BigInteger.ONE)
```

The increment statement in your loop does not modify your loop counter.

```
a.add(BigInteger.ONE)
```

This statement returns a `BigInteger`, it doesn't modify the calling object.